# Maximum distance of point from curve

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

Prove that the maximum distance of the point $(k,0) $ from the curve $2x^2+y^2-2x=0$ is $\sqrt{1-2k+2k^2}$.

I know that minimum distance is achieved along the normal to the curve from that point. Could someone give me hint to find maximum distance?

Comment: You can try this using parametric points of an ellipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: maximize the function $$f(x)=\sqrt{(x-k)^2+2x-2x^2}$$ with respect to $x$

Comment: Could you add spoilers? I am not able to understand your approach?

Comment: @Ananya $f(x)$ is the distance from $(k,0)$ to a point $(x,y)$ on the curve.

Comment: is there any general method to calculate distance of point from any curve ?